# How to Reset auto increment by a new category value in php

Tags: php, sequence

I have a field DB table structure like below:

[image: DB Structure]

Before the ID I have the PK_ID column, with this structure table is it possible to create a PHP scripts to generate something like:

PK_ID | ID | plan

- 1   | 1 | Plan Base
- 2   | 2  | Plan Base
- 3   | 1   | Plan medium

ID is autoincrement

What I want to do is, the ID value will start new sequence when new plan value added.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the counter:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = _NEW_ID_
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Thanks Denis, I tried to following that but I have the another field as PK_ID for the PK and Auto Increment. I made like this cause the when a user deleted a data the ID will sequence from last number

Comment: My query:
`$q_last_number = $this->db->query("SELECT (MAX(ID)) AS last FROM plan WHERE YEAR(date) = '".$this->session->userdata('admin')."'")->row_array();
$last = str_pad(intval($q_last_number['last']+1), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`